# Want to highlight every other row in a group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, grouping

I am trying to change the background color of every odd numbered record of each group in my SSRS report.

I know this will change the color of every even numbered record in the report.
`=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "No Color", "Silver")`

This will change the first record of each group. `=IIF(Fields!EvaluatorID.Value=previous(Fields!EvaluatorID.Value), "No Color", "Silver")`

It seems like combining them in an OR should do the trick. `=IIF((Fields!EvaluatorID.Value=previous(Fields!EvaluatorID.Value)) or (RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 1), "No Color", "Silver")`

But the color is not changing when there are 3 records in a group. Does anyone have suggestions on how to change the expression? [image]

Comment: you have mod 1 in your OR.

Comment: mod 2 highlights the even rows. I want only odd rows for each group.

Comment: Debug your own code and SEE how mod works. Add two fields (temporarily) to your report. One containing the value of "RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2" and the other containing the value of "RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 1".

Comment: mod 2 = 0 is for even and mod 2 = 1 is even. i might have this backwards if it is 0 based.

Comment: FYI => MOD 2 means the remainder after division by 2. So you are either going to have 1 or 0 as your answer. MOD 1 will always be 0.

Comment: Have you fixed the MOD 1? It's always 0 - `x MOD 1 = 0`. OTOH, SSRS doesn't always handle Boolean values well - try adding `= 1` to the end of the OR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this...

```
=IIF(RowNumber("myRowGroupName") Mod 2, "Silver", Nothing)
```

You need to specify the row group name (case sensitive and enclosed on double quotes). This evaluates rownumber() within in each group so it will start at 1 again.

Then to flip odd and even highlighting, reverse the colours that are applied. I've also used `Nothing` as this is the actual default value used in SSRS, "No Color" is just a user friendly name shown in the properties window.